# Probability, when to use Factorials and when to use Choose methods

Tags: probability

So I'm currently studying for my Statistics and Probability exam and I keep making the same problem and I've tried looking it up and researching it as much as possible but so far no luck. My question is when doing a problem how do you identify whether to use the factorial methods or a choose method. For example there here are two problems from a previous assignment:

Question 2 [12 points] Consider a team of eleven (11) soccer players, all of whom are equally 
good players and can play any position. 
(a) Suppose that the team has just finished regulation time for a play-off game and the score 
is tied with the other team. The coach has to select five players for penalty kicks to decide 
which team wins the game. For the penalty kicks, all five players selected for both teams 
take one kick each on the opposition’s net; the team with the most goals wins (for 
simplicity, assume that one of the teams always wins; there will be no ties). Since each 
player takes penalty kicks differently, the order in which the players are arranged for the 
penalty kicks is important and can affect the outcome. How many different ways (linear 
arrangements) can the coach select five (5) players to take the penalty kicks?

---

Question 3 [12 points] A game development group consists of 12 men and 13 women. 
(a) How many different project teams can be formed consisting of 5 men and 5 women?

Now I'm not asking to answer or anything, I have the solutions I just can't seem to identify the difference between the questions, like what element says that "Oh you have to use this one" I feel as if they're incredibly similar questions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction due whether specific ordering is important or not.  For your first example the order is important so the number of choices are 11*10*9*8*7, for the second it assumes that the team members are not ordered so you have count all arrangements the same by dividing number of arrangements of the choices.

Comment: Wow that makes SOOO much more sense haha it was so obvious I should have seen that. Thank you so much dude I really appreciate it!